# Why can't I use Array.join.call in place of Array.prototype.join.call

Tags: javascript

```
function test()
{
alert(Array.join.call(arguments,'/')) //alerts /
alert(Array.prototype.join.call(arguments,'/')) //alerts Js/JScript
alert(Array.join(arguments,'/')) //alerts Js/JScript
}
test('Js','JScript');
```

Why is this difference? Why is it needed to reference prototype first ?
Also why does just Array.join gives required result even when join expects just a separator argument.

Comment: This is almost certainly not J code. Please tag your question properly next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Array.join` is a global function. When using call, what you pass as a first argument is the `this` object **inside** the body of the `join` function, then the arguments for the `join` function.

```
js> Array.join.call(null, [1, 2], "/")   
"1/2"
```

`Array.prototype.join` is for instances of `Array`. Therefore, it expects `this` to be the actual array, which is why your second example works. Your second example amounts to calling `Array.prototype.join` with the `this` object being `arguments`, which is exactly `arguments.join("/")`. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) for an explanation.

Comment: +1 This is a much better answer than mine. I explained the wrong thing.

Comment: Thanks. I actually rephrased slightly to make things even clearer :)

Answer (score 1):

This is necessary because the Arguments array [isn't actually a real Array Object.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments). The specification refers to it as 'array-like', but it doesn't contain any of the methods usually associated with JavaScript Arrays, such as `join`.

Therefore what the above code is doing is calling the Array methods directly, using `call`, and passing the Arguments object as the scope of the method.

Essentially it causes the interpreter to treat the Arguments array as a real Array so that those methods can be executed on it.